# Scala proper way to initialize ones changed in runtime fields: placeholder/null, None or zero element?

Tags: scala, initialization, runtime, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I got class with fields which value at initialization is unknown. But after, in runtime that values is will gained and setted to fields **just ones**.

I want to decide what first initialization is best to use for that fields. As i read, there are such methods:

1. using placeholder `_` or `null` [**Bad way**]:

   ```
   var name: String = _
   var nextUser: User = null
   ```
2. using `None`, and than in my code `Some(v)`[**Good, but verbose**]:

   ```
   var name: Option[String] = None
   var nextUser: Option[User] = None
   ```
3. using "zero" element:

   ```
   var name: String = ""
   var nextUser: User = new User()
   ```
4. using stub:

   ```
   var name: String = "undefined"
   var nextUser: User = UndefinedUser
   ```

**I see 3 problems:**

1. it is verbose to get values from `Some()` writing any times `.get` or using `match/case`
2. it is bad to use `var` for field which really will be setted by value just one time, but in runtime
3. it is bad to write `updateUser`-like methods

Now i am using `None` in that fields, because for some types, which is not in my library, is no any `constructor` or `empty`\"zero" value:

```
class ClassWithLazyFields {

  var name: String = ""
  var age: Int = 0

  //here, after first asignment as `None` i will set it values only one time
  var myThread: Option[Thread] = None
  var nextUser: Option[User] = None
  var myTransformUnit: Option[TransformUnit] = None

  def updateUser(u: User): Unit = {
    nextUser = u
  }
}

//after first asignment as `None` i set nextUser value like that
classInstance.updateUser(userCat)

// bad ".get" in callings
val name = classInstance.myThread.get.name
val hoursToStart = classInstance.myTransformUnit.get.waitTime.hours

// or more verbose match/case
val hoursToStart = classInstance.myTransformUnit match {
  case Some(v) => v.waitTime.hours
  case None => 0
}
```

What you can advice to me?
I need something like `lazy var` or any good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice is to avoid using mutable data structures like this in the first place.

Make the class immutable and change methods like `updateUser` to return a new updated instance rather than modifying the current instance.

But if you must do this, `Option` is specifically designed for cases where values may or may not be present. Methods like `map` and `getOrElse` make it easy (and safe) to use `Option` values with very little overhead.

---

For example, this is how you safely calculate `name` and `hoursToStart`:

```
val name = classInstance.myThread.fold("NoName")(_.name)
val hoursToStart = classInstance.myTransformUnit.fold(0)(_.waitTime.hours)
```

If you want to use multiple `Option` values, use `for` like this:

```
for {
  thread <- classInstance.myThread
  user <- classInstance.nextUser
  unit <- classInstance.myTransformUnit
} {
  // Code that uses thread, user, and unit
}
```

The code will only be called if all three values are not `None`.

Comment: And what will be goodest for immutable class to use: `copy()` or own method which return new instance? `copy()` seems simple for that, but is any advantages to use methods which return new instance?

Comment: I would provide a method that uses `copy` internally, something like this: `def withUser(user: User) = this.copy(user = user)`. But even better to delay creating the object until you have the data you need.

Comment: by simple delaying creation of this instance until got all info or delay by using some language features like `lazy`?

Comment: Delay until you have all the info, if possible.